# is there a way to upload two different versions of the same image picked from gallery using Image Picker in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have issues with image sizes on my flutter e-commerce app I am building. I have tried reducing the image sizes using the max height, max width and image quality parameters, but loading times are still slow as the image sizes are still around 150kb on average because i was still trying to preserve image quality. I figured a way out of this will be to upload two versions of the same image when the user is uploading. First image will be compressed to have a size of 30kb and this will be the image to be displayed on the main pages of the app where other products are, however when a user clicks to view the product i will render the other image which has slightly better quality. The issue i am having is, when i pick an image with Image Picker, i can only set the image quality parameters once. Any way around this will be appreciated. Below is the code for how i pick the images.

```html
chooseImage() async {
    final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery,
    maxHeight: 500,
    maxWidth: 500,
    imageQuality: 50
    );

    setState(() {
      _image.add(File(pickedFile?.path));
    });
    if (pickedFile.path == null) retrieveLostData();
   

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had run into the same problem that you are facing a few months back. There is an extension on firebase called resize image. You can use this to resize the image once it's in the DB without doing it manually and complicating your app.
https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firebase-storage-resize-images

You can then save the image link in your document.